# Why does it say module has no attribute text?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

line 66, in main
I keep getting this error:

```
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.text & ~filters.command, handle_payment))
```

AttributeError: module 'telegram.ext.filters' has no attribute 'text'

Here's the code:

```
import logging
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, CallbackContext
import stripe

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

# Set up the Telegram Bot token
TELEGRAM_TOKEN = '6329888761:AAH9GPLpRE1GXrK-OCJZCfHGhbr6ExLkFKc'

# Set up the Stripe API key
STRIPE_API_KEY = '284685063:TEST:ZWVlN2Y4MzY3YjU0'

# Initialize the Stripe API client
stripe.api_key = STRIPE_API_KEY

# Define a function to handle the /start command
def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Send a welcome message when the /start command is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text('Hello! I am your Telegram bot for Stripe payments.')

# Define a function to handle payment requests
def handle_payment(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Handle payment requests and process payments using the Stripe API."""
    # Get the user's Telegram ID
    telegram_user_id = update.message.from_user.id

    # Get the payment amount from the message text
    payment_amount = update.message.text

    try:
        # Create a payment intent with Stripe
        payment_intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
            amount=int(payment_amount),
            currency='usd',
            payment_method_types=['card'],
        )

        # Get the payment intent client secret
        client_secret = payment_intent.client_secret

        # Generate a payment link for the user
        payment_link = f'https://pay.stripe.com/pay/test?client_secret={client_secret}'

        # Send the payment link to the user
        update.message.reply_text(f'Please complete the payment by clicking on the link below:\n\n{payment_link}')

    except stripe.error.StripeError as e:
        # Handle any errors from the Stripe API
        update.message.reply_text(f'Sorry, there was an error processing your payment: {e.user_message}')

def main() -> None:
    """Run the bot."""
    # Create the Updater and pass in your bot's token
    updater = Updater(TELEGRAM_TOKEN)

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    # dispatcher = updater.dispatcher (Not required in older versions)

    # Set up the command handlers
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))

    # Set up the payment handler
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.text & ~filters.command, handle_payment))

    # Start the bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I tried to update. Then I went to back to version 13. Still the same outcome

Comment: I believe you meant `filters.TEXT`, not `filters.text`

Comment: thank you so much. that fixed that particular error. I updated to newest telegram bot version but it still doesnt accept Filters.TEXT but filters.TEXT works perfectly. Much gratitude

Comment: You left your **Private Bot Token** in your code. You should revoke it **ASAP** by talking to the [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather). People might abuse the token.